# Convert Bitmap to android.media.image

Tags: java, android, bitmap

in Android how can I convert a Bitmap object into a android.media.image object?
My code is:

```
Bitmap frame;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
frame.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

How can I write bytearray in android.media.image?

Thanks,

Comment: `Image` is an `abstract` class. You cannot create instances of it, and there are no concrete subclasses in the SDK. You would have to find something that creates `Image` objects and somehow have it work with your `Bitmap`.