# How to convert Bitmap object to android.media.Image object?

Tags: android

I have an image in my drawable folder. I created a bitmap object out of it. How to convert this Bitmap object into android.media.Image Object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790623/convert-bitmap-to-android-media-image?rq=1#comment74621808_43790623

Comment: @pskink could you give me some reference, how to read the images using ImageReader